# In my dc to dc buck converter(0 to 17V - 12v), when i connect a load ,converter output voltage decreases to 1V

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, battery-operated

I try a buck converter of variable input(0 to 17) to 12V. when i connect a load with very small resistance , voltage decreases.if load increases , converter voltage looks constant.

what happens if i connet a battery in real time ?

Comment: Far too little information to even remotely help you. What kind of buck converter? Where's the schematic of that? What load? How fast? What kind of battery? Connect the battery to what?

Comment: Is the purple wire connected to the pink?

Comment: how can the coverter produce 12 V output with 0 V input?

Answer (score 1):

Your power source can source (dc converter or the power supply feeding it) can supply a limited power (P=V*I).

So in example if a power supply is set on 1W then at 10V it can source 100mA. If a 1k resistor is placed it consumes Pload = V²/R = 0.1W which is less than the power supply can provide and you get all the current you need for it.

Now if you have a 1 ohm resistor instead, Pload = 100W which is more than the source can provide. In that case the power source will operate at is limit by lowering the voltage to a level that Pload = Psupply. 
For this example the supply will drop the voltage to around 1V so the total Pload is 1W.